# How to deserialize the JSON array?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am trying to add artifacts to VM in DevTest Lab and i want to pass the artifacts name dynamically.
Below is my parameter

```
"Artifacts": {
      "type": "array"
},
```

And in Resource section am calling this as

```
"artifacts":["[parameters('Artifacts')]"]
```

Am calling this ARM as below from powershell file

```
$sampleJob += Start-Job -Name $fileName -FilePath $scriptlocation -ArgumentList  $artifact
```

$artifact is defined as object type Object[]

When running the script am getting the following error.

```
"message": "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Microsoft.DevTestLab.VirtualMachine.Data.Models.Rest.ArtifactInstallProperties' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

How to fix the above error. Any help can be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Resource section, remove the outer pair of square-brackets. It should look like:

```
"artifacts": "[parameters('Artifacts')]"
```